# How to add Magento extension in other theme except default

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add extension - [All Category Product Carousel](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all-category-product-carousel.html) in my Magento Website and it has **RWD theme**.The components of the extension are by default installing in:

1. app/design/frontend/**default**/default/layout
2. app/design/frontend/**default**/default/template
3. skin/frontend/**default**/default

I have moved the components in my theme folder i.e. RWD, and components are now in the following folders:

1. app/design/frontend/**rwd**/default/layout
2. app/design/frontend/**rwd**/default/template
3. skin/frontend/**rwd**/default

But after this also the extension is not working. I am new to Magento so does not know much things about it. Does anything else be done?

The products are there but css and js is not getting applied on them. The data is showing like: [Please View Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjkYD.png)

Comment: extension is not working means ? did you checked configuration in backend ? or is the features are not working in frontend ?

Comment: There is no data related to the category I am selecting on the website. Yes, I have verified the configuration and have inserted the shortcode in cms page.

Comment: check whether its working or not by selecting default theme under particular category or in `system > configuration > General > design` section.....

Comment: @RachitaChugh did you flushed the cache and also checked the magento log?

Comment: please explain 2 things , before moving to RWD, if extension was working? and does this extension tell to insert block in any cms page?

Comment: @Php Beginner: I have checked it is not working under default theme

Comment: @Shrikant : I have just tried it on default theme but it was not working. Yes we have to add cms block in the page/block

Comment: @Shaheer Ali : I have flushed the cache and tried

Answer (score 0):

You can paste your extension key [here](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php). Now you can check if you have copied all the files to RWD.
The extension tell to insert below block in cms page. Include it in your cms->home page.

```
{{block type="pcarousel/pcarousel" pcarousel_id="carousel id" template="pcarousel/pcarousel.phtml"}}
```

After that navigate to system->permission->blocks->Add new block and add the type `pcarousel/pcarousel` there and allow it.

Comment: Checked all the files were copied successfully and created block as well still no outcome. This problem is with other extensions also

Comment: check layout.xml file of extension and see which js and css files are used. Then  go to view page source and search for css and js files, check if they are added by clicking them

Answer (score 0):

The css and js files were not loading in the main page, have added them externally. Now working